# Track branch changes from a Makefile

Tags: git, makefile, hook

For the purposes of Makefile, how do I find out that HEAD of the current branch has changed?

I'm looking for something like this, but for a generic current branch:

```
all: report.txt

report.txt: .git/refs/heads/master
    touch report.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.git/HEAD` gives the ref of the current branch, so you can derefence `.git/HEAD`, to get the actual current branch ref.

```
all: report.txt

current := $(shell cut -c6- .git/HEAD)

report.txt: .git/${current}
        touch report.txt
```

note that if you switch branch, you will detect a *change* even if the new branch is on the same commit as the previous branch.

Answer (score 2):

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash

all: report.txt

report.txt: up-to-date
        @echo 'Updating $@'
        @touch report.txt

up-to-date: force
        @cmp -s '$@' <(git rev-parse @{0}) || git rev-parse @{0} > '$@'

force: ;
```

The `up-to-date` target compares the contents of the up-to-date file against the current revision of the HEAD ref (`@{0}` is the 0-th previous reflog entry for the current ref).

When that comparison indicates a difference it puts the new revision into the file, thus updating it and triggering make to rebuild `report.txt` which depends on it. When the comparison indicates the files are the same the file does not get updated and make sees no reason to rebuild `report.txt`.

The force target forces make to always consider up-to-date as needing to be built. You might have thought to use `.PHONY: up-to-date` instead of force but the semantics of phony targets when used as prereqs would make this not work as intended (the rule for report.txt would always be run).

Comment: @Beryllium I told myself to explain the concepts before submitting the answer but then I forgot/got lazy. Thanks for the prodding.

Comment: This isn't appearing to work. `up-to-date` never gets rerun by `make report.txt`.  You'd have to manually specify it yourself, in which this is really no better than removing force entirely.

Comment: Can you get the output from `make -d report.txt` when this fails to work? Because it shouldn't be possible for this to fail to run the `up-to-date` target.

Comment: NM figured it out, spacing around '<' and '(' and '(' and 'git' is impotant and I found someone else included a mkfile that declared `.SECONDARY` which appears to brick this

Comment: `<(command)` and `< (command)` are very different, yes. `<(...)` is Process Substitution (treat a command's output as a file and read from it). `< (...)` is redirect standard input from ... a syntax error. Space between the opening `(` and the command name doesn't matter though.

Comment: `.SECONDARY:` should just tell make to never delete a file as an intermediate but shouldn't affect this at all. The `up-to-date` file shouldn't be getting deleted by make to begin with (and explicitly telling make not to delete the file won't hurt anything because that's the behavior we want anyway).

Answer (score 1):

One of enhancement to @ndec suggested, which do not care of "detached HEAD".

Insert this before the target

```
subdir := ./                                    # can be ./src in different location 
subdep := $(subdir)/.git/HEAD                   # may have SHA-1 (detached HEAD) 
gitref := $(word 2, $(shell cat $(subdep)))     # may be a ref HEAD (for any branch/tag) 
ifneq "$(gitref)" ""                            # append it if referenced HEAD
    subdep += $(subdir)/.git/$(gitref)          # e.g. HEAD & refs/heads/master 
endif
```

Then you can add $(subdep) to the target dependency, e.g.

```
report.txt: $(subdep)
    @touch $@
```

Then the target will be built if branch or commit changes.